# TypeUtils says "null" is instance of "Object.class"?

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons

Regarding following code `org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.TypeUtils` says `null` is a type of `Object.class`. Isn't this incorrect ?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Boolean bool = null;

    if (TypeUtils.isInstance(bool, Object.class)) {
        System.out.println("bool isInstance Object-true");
    } else {
        System.out.println("bool isInstance Object-false");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you. The `isInstance()` method is misleading.
It should be rather `isAssignable()` since the documentation indicates it :

> Checks if the given value can be assigned to the target type following
>   the Java generics rules.

**And null is not a instance of Object class since null is not an instance.**

But your result is accurate according to the documentation since `null` can be assigned to any object type.
And when you look the implementation, you can see that the code calls a `isAssignable()` method :

```
public static boolean isInstance(final Object value, final Type type) {
    if (type == null) {
        return false;
    }

    return value == null ? !(type instanceof Class<?>) || !((Class<?>) type).isPrimitive()
            : isAssignable(value.getClass(), type, null);
}
```

Comment: It would be great if we align naming of this method with the "job it's doing".

Comment: Such a method name is prone to introducing errors in application as it's misleading. Even though went through documentation, but it didn't make me realize about boundary condition like "null". It's my mistake I agree, but I think there is a scope of improvement, perhaps by renaming it to isAssignable(). We can narrow down the error margin, that way.

Comment: I agree with you. I notice that isAssignable() is overloaded multiple times in that class.  I have the impression that Class authors would make the distinction when the parameter is an instance (in all isAssignable() , only types are used in parameters) but it's very awkward  since misleading. 
isAssignable() should be enough for all cases. And if a distinction was needed, isTypeAssignable() and isInstanceAssignable() seems more relevant.

Answer (score 2):

It's correct. The [function's documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/TypeUtils.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.reflect.Type)) says the following:

> Checks if the given value can be assigned to the target type following
>   the Java generics rules.

And since you can assign `null` to a variable of type `Object`, this returns true.

Without that documentation, you would be correct in my opinion since `null` means there is no instance, regardless of the type.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/TypeUtils.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.reflect.Type) .

The method just checks if null can be assigned to an Object , it will return true i guess.